# Making PM system's Inbox - Dynamically link Panel controls

Tags: mysql, vb.net, custom-controls

**Ignore this to get to the main problem, below is only the idea**

Scenario: I am making a total Private Messaging system in Visual Basic.

Trying: I want to make an Inbox for the users. The messages will be retrieved from the MySQL database and shown in small custom Grid made with Panel(Type of Control from Visual basic) for each message which will be clickable which is when clicked, the whole message will be shown.

Did so far: Not too much though(Talking about the Inbox.), I only wrote the MySQL query.
I will make the Sending and Reading PM after the Inbox as Inbox seems more complex than the other two things.

I really want to know how can this be achieved. I searched around almost everywhere, either it was for PHP and web based or nothing. I want to know how to dynamically create controls like panels and the labels and show the PMs. Is there any other way to do this rather than showing the PMs in DataGridView ? (I really don't want to use that as it's not what I want.)

For reference: The custom Grid is something like this:
[image: The Grid for each message.]

The MySQL PM table: 
`PMId - The ID for the message (Auto Incremented)
Sender_Name - The person sending the message
Receiver_Name - The person receiving the message
Subject - The subject of the message
Date_Sent - Date on which the message was sent
PM_Read - If the PM has been read (0 for not read, 1 for read)
Deleted - If the PM has been deleted (0 for not deleted, 1 for deleted)`

Comment: `MySQL query` - forget SQL. Use an ORM. `either it was for PHP and web based or nothing` - If you want to achieve the UI flexibility of Web technologies, while retaining the stateful goodness and full-blown access to everything of a desktop app, you should use WPF. winforms is a really old legacy technology that's not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications, and it doesn't have any support for any sort of customization.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into those, but are you saying there's no way to do it in Windows Forms ?

Comment: I'm not saying there is "no way". I'm saying winforms isn't intended for any kind of custom UI, and it doesn't support any form of customization/styling (think CSS for HTML). It also doesn't support (real) DataBinding which means you have to write more code to achieve less (than with current technologies). It doesn't make any sense to use winforms for anything, except if you plan to run your software on a 386 machine with DOS 5.0 from 50 years ago...

Comment: Ah ok, What If I don't use winforms ? And use the default.vb forms ? Anything could be done ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're talking about.. VB6? that is even more dead than winforms

Comment: I am using Visual Basic 2013, And I made my whole program in Windows Form with the extension of .vb not the User Control (WPF) forms with extension .xaml. Which form should I use to achieve my prospective goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code-behind for a built form and you will see how to create controls at run-time. For example, I created a form, added a panel with a button and label and this is the code created in the designer:

```
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 29)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Label1.Text = "Label1"
        '
        'Panel1
        '
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
        Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(198, 69)
        Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 2
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.Panel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.Panel1.PerformLayout()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
```

You can do the same thing at run-time.

```
    Dim iTop As Int32 = 5
    For Each DR As DataRow In DT.Rows
        Dim pnl As New Panel
        pnl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, iTop)
        pnl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(198, 40)
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
        lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        lbl.Text = DR("Some field from your table")

        'Add to panel
        pnl.Controls.Add(lbl)

        'Add to Form
        Me.Controls.Add(pnl)

        'Add to the top location so the next set of controls are not on top of the old ones
        iTop += 50
    Next
```

Comment: That informative, but how can I create such panel for every row returned by the MySQL query just down to each other just like the message in the inbox we see. Thank you for trying, waiting for the reply. And Can I know how you got that code-behind the built form

Comment: For each row, declare a new panel and related controls. You don't have to declare them as Friend WithEvents....  You don't even have to name them.

Comment: I re-edited my comment while you were posting, can you give some example code or something ? Just some little ? I am just not getting the point. :/

Comment: To get the code behind, in the solution explorer window there is a button with a tooltip of "Show All Files". This will show you the files VS creates for you.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, The label is not updated and the messages are not retrieved. Possible reason? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I would suggest you STEP through the code to figure out what is wrong. I cannot see anything missing from what you posted. Sorry.

Comment: I have wrote the Private Sub InitializeComponent() code in the designer code. Is it alright ? or where do I have to use that ?

Comment: Ignore my stupidity of yesterday, was tired. I have updated the code and the main post. Please take a look.

Comment: @user328430 Your issue has changed and you should create a new post.

Comment: Erm, ok! I thought that would be spamming/Multi threading here.